# Is there a linguistic reason why we sometimes use a singular pronoun and verb even when it refers to a plural subject?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, dummy-it, notional-concord

Here is the [exact quote](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Why_is_a_Red_Herring_Red/qCf4DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Consequently,+when+the+herd+is+hunted,+it+is+the+slowest+and+weakest+ones+at+the+back+that+are+killed+first.&pg=PT134&printsec=frontcover) from *Why is a Red Herring Red?* by Mitchell Symons (2020):

> Consequently, when the herd is hunted, **it is** the slowest and weakest **ones** at the back that are killed first.

Comment: 'It is John.' 'It is John and Judy.' 'It is them.' Clefting uses 'it is' invariantly, and may involve a singular or a plural delayed subject (here, 'the slowest and weakest ones at the back', essentially from 'When the herd is hunted, the slowest and weakest ones at the back are killed first.'

Comment: The plural in _ones_ comes from the fact that _herd_ is a group noun, and consists of individuals together.

Comment: The pronoun “it” is not referential here, but a meaningless dummy element functioning as subject in an _it_-cleft construction, where the foregrounded element is complement of "is". The pronoun is really just a 'placeholder' for the variable that is defined in the relative clause; it does not have the number properties of the NP headed by plural "ones”.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> The plural in *ones* comes from the fact that *herd* is a group noun, and consists of individuals together.

Also in a comment BillJ wrote:

> The pronoun “it” is not referential here, but a meaningless dummy element functioning as subject in an *it*-cleft construction, where the foregrounded element is complement of "is". The pronoun is really just a 'placeholder' for the variable that is defined in the relative clause; it does not have the number properties of the NP headed by plural "ones”.